# [ROS2] How to set the logfile

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm using a logger with ROS2 dashing. I couldn't find any explanation, how I can change the logger to log to a file instead of std output and how I can set the logfile.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328137/%5Bros2%5D-how-to-set-the-logfile/) by [Andreas Ziegler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40817/andreas-ziegler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's still a work in progress, see:

https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-logging/6469/28

We wanted to have it for Dashing, but the log4cxx implementation had issues so we pulled it from the release.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0